# UIImage don't release memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, objective-c-blocks

I have a strange problem with memory management which makes me crazy. I need to preload images asynchronously. I have a code

```
- (void)preloadFinishAnimation
{
    self.animationImages = [NSMutableArray new];
    __weak LearningViewController *weakSelf = self;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ANIMATION_FRAMES; i++) {
            UIImage *problemImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"success-%d", i]];
            [weakSelf.animationImages addObject:[weakSelf renderedImageFromImage:image]];
            problemImage = nil;
        }
    });
}


- (UIImage *)renderedImageFromImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [image drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return renderedImage;
}
```

I checked with Instruments, and I know that problemImage don't release memory. Here is retain/release commands for one of problemImages.

[image]

Hope someone knows where the problem is!

Comment: First detail, I'm sure everyone wants to know, is: are you using ARC?

Comment: Also, does not the Allocation Summary show that the image was released? Looks to me that there is a release for every retain.

Comment: First thing, if you are using ARC then there is no need to worry about renderedImage instance. Otherwise, you require to autorelease this reference in renderedImageFromImage method.

Comment: I'm using ARC. No, it's not released. In Allocation summary in the last line RefCt is 1. And I'm looking for only live objects.

Comment: all images loaded by `imageNamed:` are cached by framework to improve performance. What is more imported if you call twice `imageNamed:` with same name, memory will be shared between those two objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use `imageWithContentsOfFile:` or `initWithContentsOfFile:` instead of `imageNamed:` as `imageNamed:` will always cache the image until the system requests more memory and therfore purges cached images.

Answer (score 2):

UIImage imageNamed: caches the images and will release the memory on it's own schedule. 
use "imageWithContentsOfFile":

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:nil]]
```